# Name error when trying to reference function parameter

Tags: python

I am getting Name error when I try to run the code below

```
def multiply(x,y):
  x = int(input("Enter a whole number: "))
  y = int(input("Enter a whole number: "))
  return x * y
print(x, "*", y, "=", multiply())
```

Output:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-611728e87d5f> in <module>()
      3   y = int(input("Enter a whole number: "))
      4   return x * y
----> 5 print(x, "*", y, "=", multiply())

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def multiply(): 
    x = int(input("Enter a whole number: ")) 
    y = int(input("Enter a whole number: ")) 

    return(str(x)+ "*"+ str(y)+ "="+str(x*y))


print(multiply())
```

Comment: @MohamedMustafa please accept and upvote this if it is work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `x` and `y` are variables in the function `multiply()`. They don't exist outside of the function.

It is usually a bad idea to write a function that does some processing and also prints and reads. If  function prints or reads, then it should do only that.

But if you really want a function to read two variables and return the variables and their product, you could do like this:

```
def read_and_multiply():
  n1 = int(input("Enter a whole number: "))
  n2 = int(input("Enter a whole number: "))
  m = n1 * n2
  return n1, n2, m

x, y, m = read_and_multiply()
print(x, "*", y, "=", m)
```